# Bootstrap 4 element location CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I apologize for the bad english. I need to raise the element almost to the top of the page. I've been adjusting the code for an hour and nothing comes out. Help me please.
[How it look's now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f3BX.jpg)
[How it look's when apply nav-scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xFrP.jpg)

HTML:

```
  <header id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
        <a href="#intro"><img src="img/logonav2.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
      </div>

      <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="menu-active"><a href="#intro">О нас</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Партнеры</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">Контакты</a></li>

          <li><a href="#contact">Поддержка</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 92px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
}

#header.header-scrolled {
  background: #1d3138;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 72px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#header #logo {
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #header #logo {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
}

#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#header #logo h1 a, #header #logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 4px solid #18d26e;
}

#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header #logo h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much! This site ask me to add more details, but i don't know, what i need to say

Comment: Which element do you want to have at the top? Anyway, one suspicious thing is that you have position: fixed for your header.